# Skipping KeyDown On Override ProcessCmdKey EventHandller

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a simple increment on textbox by pressing down arrow key which are as below.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

     if (keyData == Keys.Down)
     {

           int c = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
           c++;
           textBox1.Text = c.ToString();


     }
 }
```

The above works on pressing double down arrow key instead of single pressing down arrow key.

Note: The above code is on UserControl. And  I have tried it on simple winform application on form keydown  EventHandller and the same is works fine.

How to overcome?.

Comment: What do you mean "the same is works fine"? I'm curious because you say you used the KeyDown handler of the textbox, which is the correct method to use.

Comment: The method returns a bool.  Return true if you used the key.

Comment: @HansPassant, Yes you are absolutely wright I agreed with you just need to return value of bool as it is bool method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to handle other commands that existed before and return when you handle ones you are looking for.  Try changing it to this and see if that helps:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
   if (msg.WParam.ToInt32() == (int)Keys.Down)
   {
      int c = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
      c++;
      textBox1.Text = c.ToString();
      return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: yes your trick is works and I also agreed with Mr. HansPassant that there are only need to return true on use of key as the above method return bool.

Comment: @MaheshWagh - Glad I could help, dont forget to accept the answer if it is what you were looking for